# Display all records from db with empty form fields

Tags: php, mysql, forms

is it possible to get all records from database when you do not enter any field in the form

something like this, some sort of conditional query
I have one query $query that get me some data after filling form, but I need an evet to display all data from database when fields country and work are empty
there are also two other date fields to filter results in some time interval
code is :
...

```
$country = $_GET['country'];
$work = $_GET['work'];

if ($country == 0 and $work == 0)
echo $query1;
else $query;

$query1 = "SELECT ...."
$query = "SELECT...."
```

.....

thanks

EDIT> 
Hi, i tried that and it returns all data witch is OK. _But now I have error: Query was empty when I fill form fields. code si like this:

```
if (empty($country) and empty($work))
{
$query1 = "SELECT row_number, country, project_type, code, start_date, end_date, work, name
FROM eng WHERE 
start_date
BETWEEN \"$start_date\" and \"$end_date\"
ORDER BY country ASC";
};
$query = "
SELECT row_number, country, project_type, code, start_date, end_date, work, name
FROM eng WHERE 
country = \"$country\" AND work LIKE '%$work%' AND start_date
BETWEEN \"$start_date\" and \"$end_date\"
ORDER BY start_date ASC";
$qry_result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
$qry_result1 = mysql_query($query1) or die(mysql_error());
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if (empty($country) and empty($work)){
$query = "SELECT * from table....";
};
```

That should work fine.

Also, you should rather use the `POST` method with forms, not `GET`.

Comment: Hi, i tried that and it returns all data witch is OK. _But now I have error: Query was empty when I fill form fields. code si like this:

Comment: You've put both the qry_result commands at the end, you need to put the 2nd one inside the {}.